# Probability of triangle formation from 3 rods

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Three different rods of unit length are cut at a random point. What is the probability that 3 pieces hence generated will form a:
1) triangle
2) acute triangle.

What I did was that we have:

```
x+y > z
y+z > x
z+x > y.
```

These lines should enclose a figure in 3 dimensions and we can divide by area of cube to get these values. But is there a way I can solve this staying in 2D. I still have no clue for 2nd part.

Comment: For the 2nd part. If $\theta$ is the angle between the side $x$ and $y$, then $\cos\theta = \frac{x^2+y^2-z^2}{2xy}$. If the triangle is acute, then $\cos\theta \ge 0 \iff x^2+y^2 > z^2$. The condition for the other two angles are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular problem, a picture worths more than thousand words.

[image: Admissible configuration of acute triangle]

- The brown figure above is the admissible region for $(x,y,z) \in [0,1]^3$ 
  for forming acute triangles, it is bounded by 3 planes and 3 conical surfaces
  $$x = 1, y = 1, z = 1\quad\text{ and }\quad
  x^2+y^2 = z^2, y^2+z^2 = x^2, z^2 + x^2 = y^2$$
  It can be obtained from the unit cube by chopping off 3 "quarter" cones.
  This means its volume equals to $1 - 3\left(\frac14\cdot \frac{\pi}{3}\right) = 1 - \frac{\pi}{4}$.
- The blue semi-transparent region is the extra admissible region 
  for forming non-acute triangles. As one can see, the admissible region for
  forming triangle (acute or not) are bounded by 6 planes
  $$x = 1, y = 1, z = 1\quad\text{ and }\quad
  x + y = z, y + z = x, z + x = y$$
  It can be obtained from the unit cube by chopping off 3 triangular pyramids.
  Its volume is given by $1 - 3\left(\frac16\right) = \frac12$.